# How to find correct projection for HDF5 data?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, hdf

I have downloaded this [dataset](http://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/lai) and I need to work with it and with this [dataset](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-physical-vectors/).

I do not know which projection to set to HDF5 data, because it is not correct in any projection.

Comment: Is that data available because I can't find a download link. The docs say "metadata according to the Climate and Forecast (CF) conventions v1.6" and give a description of the grid in the "technical" section so what more do you need? See also section 4.3 of the User Manual http://land.copernicus.eu/global/sites/default/files/products/GIOGL1_PUM_LAI300m-V1_I1.41.pdf

Comment: Yes i have read what i need?  i need project this data in ArcMap correct. I need to know, which projection is correct

Comment: 1. Is that data available because I can't find a download link to it. 2. that's the first time you've mentioned ArcMap. 3. The documentation tells you all the parameters - its WGS84, lat-long plate carree 80N to 60S, grid size 1/336 degree. 4. Can ArcMap read CF Convention Metadata? If so, it should read it in. If not then you need to find out how to set raster bounds in ArcMap. What have you tried? What have you got? Error messages? Data in the wrong place? Show us!

Comment: thank for your comment :-)  i recorded video with my work with this raster. https://youtu.be/ru9A6cbRD1E.  Wrong place and wrong scale :-/

Comment: You need to set the extent of the raster as well as the projection if ArcMap can't pick it up from the metadata. 80N to 60S, 180W to 180E (plus possibly half a cell size). Sorry I don't know how to set that in ArcMap (QGIS user!)

Comment: no problem, I use qgis too, but i dont know what do you mean "set the extent of the raster as well as the projection,80N to 60S, 180W to 180E (plus possibly half a cell size " or where  I can set it in qgis :-/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50952/discussion-between-komy-and-spacedman).

Comment: It's obvious what is being asked here, it's really common that model output uses a projection but doesn't specify it explicitly. It needs experience to resurrect.+1